# How can I construct a bash-safe filename from a string?

Tags: replace, string, filenames, format

I want to generate very simple filenames from complex strings during a org-capture.
For instance the string

`"Une idée nouvelle pour calculer $\\int_0^{\\infty} e^{-t^2} \\dd t$"`

Should be reduced to
`une_idee_nouvelle_pour_calculer_int_0_infty_e_-t_2_dd_t.org`
or something equivalent.

Should I use `replace-regexp-in-string` with appropriate regexp (that I have trouble building) or is there a more canonical way ?

Non comprehensive specification list :

- remove spaces (replace with underscore)
- only alphanumeric ascii characters (no symbols, no other unicode...), the rest is deleted
- (if possible) intelligent replacement "Å" -> "A"
- (if possible but seems hard) trim obvious gibberish from parts with way too many characters removed.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2):

I found a melpa package which does just that and properly : [unidecode](https://melpa.org/#/unidecode)

```
(unidecode-sanitize "Une idée nouvelle pour calculer $\\int_0^{\\infty} e^{t^2} \\dd t$")


"une-idee-nouvelle-pour-calculer-int0infty-et2-dd-t"
```